# Was this event in the opening montage related to similar events later on in the show?

Tags: ares

In the opening montage of Dutch horror series [*Ares*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ares_(TV_series)), an (unnamed?) young woman

> gets raped by a fellow student association member, is consoled by a character later introduced as Carmen, and then commits suicide.

Later in the series, Jacob, one of the protagonists, finds a mysterious

> dark spot on a wall that engulfs two of his fingers.

He is later shown to touch several members of the association

> with his fingers, who will apparently fall into despair and commit suicide.

Is the event from the opening montage related to the later

> suicides?

My impression from watching the first season was that it's basically what happened to Jacob (and what he did then) that caused things to go awry for the titular *Ares* society.

However, the way Carmen knowingly smiles at the unnamed novice in the initial montage<sup>1</sup> makes me think it's implied Carmen instructs the novice "what to do next". (On the other hand, Carmen does appear visibly shocked when it actually happens.)

So, what's going on here?

- Are the events in the montage basically unrelated to what happens later on, thereby setting the tone for the show in a somewhat misleading way?
- Are the events related and there's more to Carmen than what is shown during the first season?
- Or are the events unrelated, and Carmen just happens to be involved in this one, whereas the events throughout the rest of the season are triggered by Jacob's actions?

---

<sup>1</sup>: In the song that plays in the background ("Zing, vecht, huil, bid, lach, werk en bewonder" by Ramses Shaffy), that's approximately when the words "Zing, vecht" are sung for the third time in the second occurrence of the refrain.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. My impression is that this event sets the stage for certain other events later on.

First, and most importantly, it establishes that there is an influence at Ares that can cause people to commit suicide. Further, the man with black hair, whose name I do not recall, is shown to be a rapist who uses parties as a cover, which sets the scene for what he does to Rosa. Overall, the vignettes we see also establish Ares as an organization full of cold-hearted people, that would swallow an optimistic person like the unnamed novitiate whole.

I doubt that Carmen was involved in the death of the novitiate, except insofar as she might have given her something to feel regret over. I think her smile was just a superior smirk, which the members of Ares in general, and Carmen in particular, seem to be quite fond of. As to *what* the connection was between what happened to her and what Jacob was doing to people....

To elaborate on the direct connection. 
At the beginning, they were asking Jacob whether he had ever had any thoughts of suicide. I suspect that they thought that a person who was already inclined to suicide might be suspectible to the influence of what I will call the "Beal pool" (although this is not quite accurate). Given that Jacob had been below, they were concerned that it might have drawn him to it, as indeed seems to have been the case. Perhaps she had come into contact with it by touching the wall, but, unlike Jacob, might have succumbed to it. After all, it seems to have had some negative effect on Rosa's mother, without her having been touched by someone who had in turn come into contact with the pool.

It  is worth noting that, even without knowing that Jacob had come into contact with the pool, they suspected that the pool was somehow behind the rash of suicides. Clearly, the pool exerts some influence at a distance. Otherwise, how do people begin to eliminate their "offerings"? There are clearly differing degrees of sensitivity, as we see at the end:

> When confronted with a substantially larger portion of "Beal" than Jacob had on his fingers, at least one person commits suicide immediately, some do later, and some stay alive at least long enough to run into the street.

I think someone could be affected by the pool without even coming into contact with it. In fact—although this is speculation—I think we can take a guess as to why. The black vomit is connected to guilt and regret. Rosa started exhibiting it extremely early compared to the other members of Ares, and this probably be attributed to her feeling more regret for smaller things than the other members, who basically had been socialized into sociopathy. So she seemed particularly susceptible to the influence of the pool. Similarly, Jacob, who had more misgivings about Ares than the rest, was drawn to the pool rather rapidly. The woman we saw at the beginning seemed to wear her feelings on her sleeve—so she might have felt the influence of the pool relatively early, just like the previous two. But she lacked something—force of personality? a purpose?—that prevented Rosa and Jacob from committing suicide even after direct contact.

In fact, certain dialogue suggests that the pool was "restless" or "uneasy" even before Jacob touched the wall. Jacob touching the wall was arguably *caused* by this uneasiness.

So I would go with options 1 and 2. The events are related, but it also could be viewed as setting the tone.